# react-feather icon "SVGAnimatedString" is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the `import { User } from 'react-feather'`. However, I can't figure out why is it when I use the line of code `console.log(e.target.parentNode.className);`

I get this...

[image]

But when I change that line of code to `console.log(e.target.parentNode.className.SVGAnimatedString);`

I get this...

[image]

Is there anyway to get some consistency?

**Edit:** I drummed up the sandbox to re-produce the error https://codesandbox.io/s/ll9v23qzyz

(Note): Click on the black line(child of the icon) to re-produce the error.

Comment: "SVGAnimatedString" is the constructor of the Object you accessed as `.className` property. If you wish to access `"UserIconDropdown"`  string, then it's `e.target.parentNode.className.baseVal`, or even better `e.target.parentNode.classList.toString()` if you want your code to work both with SVG and HTML elements

Comment: Awesome! It worked with `e.target.parentNode.classList.toString()`. Now I can use my `.includes()` without an error throw. Thanks a bunch @Kaiido :D

Comment: Solution code -> https://codesandbox.io/s/vy5p34y0v5